# Changing values in a specific column in a list

Tags: python, astronomy

I have a large data file that I want to edit a bit. I'm checking if the value in a certain column (column 8  in this case) has the same value in multiple lines, and if it reaches the same amount of lines as my "multiplicity" variable I'm saving those lines into a new array. If however this amount is not reached, I want to change the value in another column (column 5) for the lines checked to the amount of lines reached (i.e. my "count" variable). This is where my code is not working.

```
multiplicity=7
complete_systems=[]       
for i in range(len(matching_rows)):
    count = 0
    value=matching_rows[i][8]
    for j in range(len(matching_rows)):
        if matching_rows[j][8]==value:
            count+=1
    if count ==multiplicity:
        complete_systems.append(matching_rows[i])
    else count for matching_rows[i][5] in matching_rows:
        complete_systems.append(matching_rows[i])
```

where matching_rows is my array. Example lines:

```
[memmap(['K00806.02', '60.32494216', '12.19', '89.83', '0.2998', '5', '22',
         '0.8670', '0.9860', '347.20'],
        dtype='<U12'),
 memmap(['K00806.01', '143.2063047', '8.9', '89.83', '0.5336', '5', '9',
         '0.8670', '0.9860', '138.80'],
        dtype='<U12'),
 memmap(['K00232.05', '56.2590881', '2.22', '89.97', '0.287', '5', '22',
         '1.1910', '0.9950', '29.70'],
        dtype='<U12'),
```

So the code works up until the ELSE part, which just returns an Invalid Syntax error. I don't have much experience with programming so would love some hints!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to have done the job!

```
if count ==multiplicity:
        complete_systems.append(matching_rows[i])
else:
        matching_rows[i][5]=count
        complete_systems.append(matching_rows[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
else count for matching_rows[i][5] in matching_rows:
```

has no meaning in Python. First of all, else required colon after it:

```
else:
```

You probably mean

```
elif count for matching_rows[i][5] in matching_rows:
```

but

```
count for matching_rows[i][5] in matching_rows:
```

still has no meaning in Python. You probably wanted

```
matching_rows[i][5] in matching_rows:
```

so the complete statement should be

```
elif matching_rows[i][5] in matching_rows:
```

Comment: Ah, I realize now that `for` in this instance probably initiates a for loop. For some reason I thought it could be used to replace values (as in set "count" for the value in line "i" column 5 in matching_rows...). Gonna try some other approach with your answer in mind!